# Highcharts add array values to export csv

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need help in highcharts export csv plugin. All it can do is to export csv file but limited only on x-axis,y-axis and series. I want to add another array but not shown in the graph to be export in csv file.

What I have in my json result are arrays of integer, arrays of date, arrays of value.

In my graph,x-axis is array of integer, y-axis was the value. arrays of date was not included in the graph and maybe that's the reason when I click export csv. Date is not included. I want to add the date on the exported csv file.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: U can do it in navigator section, like this:

`navigator: {
        series: {
            data: [2016],
            includeInCSVExport: true 
        }
    },`

Comment: Can you show a demo?

Comment: Sure http://jsfiddle.net/2Jyn5/264/ but in this case u can only add numbers, not strings

Comment: Can't it be with the button on the graph?

Comment: Add the exporting.js reference and then you willl have that option in button. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/op0wbvp4/

Comment: @SebastianBochan no, what I want is to add another data to be exported not limited to what is on the graph

Comment: @SebastianBochan you are using highstock. The navigator function. THat's what I need but not on highstock.

Comment: So where you need that? Could you describe step by step your goal?

Comment: Edited my question please see